# Cannot get HTTP POST's body in FastCGI application

Tags: http, post, nginx, fastcgi

I am using a library from http://fastcgi.com/ in C++ application as a backend and nginx web-server as a front-end.

Posting 1MB file from HTML-form successful and the variable "CONTENT_LENGTH" is large enough :) But i can't figure out how to access a body of POST request using libfcgi. This is my HTML-form, it works great.

```
<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<input type="test" name="text1" /> 
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

Request is accepted via

```
int FCGX_Accept_r(FCGX_Request *request);
```

Inside the FCGX_Request we have 3 streams: in, out, err. The "in" stream has flag isReader == 1, other's isReader == 0.

```
typedef struct FCGX_Stream {
   unsigned char *rdNext;    /* reader: first valid byte
                              * writer: equals stop */
   unsigned char *wrNext;    /* writer: first free byte
                              * reader: equals stop */
   unsigned char *stop;      /* reader: last valid byte + 1
                              * writer: last free byte + 1 */
   unsigned char *stopUnget; /* reader: first byte of current buffer
                              * fragment, for ungetc
                              * writer: undefined */
   int isReader;
   int isClosed;
   int wasFCloseCalled;
   int FCGI_errno;                /* error status */
   void (*fillBuffProc) (struct FCGX_Stream *stream);
   void (*emptyBuffProc) (struct FCGX_Stream *stream, int doClose);
   void *data;
} FCGX_Stream;
```

The difference between all the pointers rdNext, wrNext, stop == 0. The difference (stop - stopUnget) is about 0x500.

Reading the data between stopUnget and stop give me the "FASTCGI-dump" sent by nginx to my application, but no data sent via form.

Though, sniffer between nginx and fastcgi application show nginx sending HTTP POST's body correctly, including 1MB jpeg file.

So, it is not clean how to get the data sent by HTML form via POST request.

Answer (score 4):

libfcgi provides three functions to read from the input stream, `FCGX_GetStr`, `FCGX_GetLine` and `FCGX_GetChar`.

```
while (FCGX_GetStr(buf, sizeof(buf), request.in) > 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You will need to take care of parsing the `multipart/form-data` body.